# What is your method to generate Websphere 6 EJB with Ant / JDK 1.4.x?

Tags: java, ant, websphere, ejb

The only working method I found, several years ago, was :

1. Generating ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi and ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi for each session bean by using XDoclet (ejbdoclet task)
2. Making a jar (without stubs) with task jar; ;
3. Calling the binary EJBDEPLOY with this jar without stub in parameters.

But I feel there must be a cleaner method. Which is yours ?

Answer (score 1):

i use the wsejbdeploy ant task, if you are using ws_ant that comes with RAD then you can have something like the below in your build file

```
<taskdef name="wsejbdeploy" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsEjbDeploy"/>
<wsejbdeploy inputJar="${EjbJarFile}" outputJar="${tempEjbJarFile}" workingDirectory="${tempWS.dir}"  noWarnings="true" classpathref="project.classpath"/>
```